# detecting any keystroke in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that needs to wait until any key is pressed. For example:

```
System.out.println("press any key to continue");
//wait until any keystroke
obj.doSomething;
```

the key that is pressed doesn't matter and I don't need to capture what key was pressed, I just need the program to wait until a key is depressed to continue.

Comment: Generally, it can't be achieved in Java without resorting to use JNI/JNA

Answer (score 1):

The official Java Tutorials describe how to implement Key Listeners for this purpose:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html